# Unity3D Transition Condition does not work

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

The walk layer in the animator is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr39I.png). When player is walking, it puts IsWalking true, but the animation does not start. Why?
[Here is transition in inspector.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTF32.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `New State` is the default State. So when the game starts, it sets its state to this. There is no connection between the `New State` and the `Walking` so it never plays. You need to create a transition between the `New State` and the `Walking`. Not the `Entry` and `Walking`.

Comment: Thanx a lot, that solved my problem. If you do not mind, I want to ask another question. Are there any ways of stopping animation without disabling animator?

Comment: Make a transition from the ``Walking`` -> ``New State``. Set the transition condition to when ``IsWalking`` is false and then you can switch between walking animation and no animation by setting the ``IsWalking`` parameter. If walking animation seems to be taking too long to finish, make sure you uncheck the **Has exit time** option on both transitions. If you have any more problems with this, you should probably create a new question or just google a bit :)

Comment: Thanx again! 
ps
Unfortunately google told me to disable animator or use coroutines.